# Wrong output when creating an account (Object)

Tags: java

I'm having issues with my program which is a subclass of another program I wrote called account. I create an account (george) and set values to it, a string for name, int id, and double balance. I'm not getting any errors but the only correct value is the string for name. I think it has to do something with my Overridden toString() method in the account class not grabbing the correct values.

My output:

```
Account holder name: George
Account id: 0
Annual interest: 1.5
Monthly Interest Rate: 0.00125
Balance 109.0
Transaction:
```

Correct ouput:

```
Account holder name: George
Account id: 1122
Annual interest: 0.015
Monthly Interest Rate: 0.013862499999999998
balance: 1109.0
Transaction:
type: d amount: 30.0 balance: 1030.0 deposit
type: d amount: 40.0 balance: 1070.0 deposit
type: d amount: 50.0 balance: 1120.0 deposit
type: w amount: 5.0 balance: 1115.0 withdrawal
type: w amount: 4.0 balance: 1111.0 withdrawal
type: w amount: 2.0 balance: 1109.0 withdrawal
```

CustomerAccount.class :

```
public class CustomerAccount extends Account {

public static String name;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CustomerAccount george = new CustomerAccount("George", 1122, 1000.0);
    george.setannualInterest(1.5);
    Account c1 = george;

    george.deposit(30);
    george.deposit(40);
    george.deposit(50);

    george.withdraw(5);
    george.withdraw(4);
    george.withdraw(2);

    System.out.println(c1.toString());

    CustomerAccount john = new CustomerAccount("John", 1123, 500);
    john.setannualInterest(2.5);
    Account c2 = john;

    ArrayList<CustomerAccount> sort = new ArrayList<CustomerAccount>();
    //sort.add(c1);
    //sort.addAll(c2);

}

    CustomerAccount(String name, int id, double balance) {
        this.name = name;
        id = getId();
        balance = getBalance();
}

   ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
}
```

Transaction class:

```
class Transaction extends Account {
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    private char type;
    private double amount;
    private double balance;
    private String description;
    private double transaction;

Transaction() {

}

Transaction(char type, double amount, double balance, String description) {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    this.type = type;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated.toString();
}

public char getType() {
    return type;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getTransaction() {
    return this.transaction;
}

public void setType(char type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setTransaction(double amount) {
    this.transaction = amount;
}
}
```

Account.class :

```
class Account {
    private int id = 0;
    private double balance = 0.0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

// set dateCreated for the time and date the account was created
Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
}

// Set accounts id and balance equal to this objects
Account(int id, double balance){
    this();
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
}

// Getters and Setters manipulating variables to be set to the created account
// Setters have no return value and set itself equal to the variable and getters 
// grab the variables and return them.
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
}

public double getannualInterestRate() {
    return this.annualInterestRate;
}

public String getDateCreated() {
    return this.dateCreated.toString();
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public void setannualInterest(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}

public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    return (annualInterestRate / 100) / 12;
}

public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate();
}

// set balance of withdraw to balance - amount = balance
public void withdraw (double amount) {
    if(amount < balance) {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}

// set balance of deposit to balance + amount = balance
public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
    //Transaction.add(new Transaction('D', amount, balance, "Deposit to account"));
}   

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account holder name: " + CustomerAccount.name + 
            "\nAccount id: " + id + 
            "\nAnnual interest: " + this.getannualInterestRate() + 
            "\nMonthly Interest Rate: " + this.getMonthlyInterestRate() + 
            "\nBalance " + this.getBalance() +
            "\nTransaction: ";
}
}
```

Comment: What should the correct output be?

Comment: You've posted a *lot* of code here. You should work to reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Why is the expected output for annualInterestRate 0.015 when you set it to 1.5 in main?  If you want it to show in percent rather than decimal, its not doing that in the getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the values in the Account class, you need to call

```
super(id, balance)
```

in the CustomerAccount constructor to call the constructor for Account

Try that

Comment: Yeah I need to find a way to add the transactions to the array everytime the withdraw/deposit methods are activated. Then I plan on using a for loop to print those after, but I want the correct outputs of everything above transaction before moving onto that.

Comment: Try the protected change in Account class and let me know if that fixes your output

Comment: Also changing them to protected in the class Account has no effect on my output, still the same values.